# Kafka Consumer does not read data from Producer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, data-science

My Kafka consumer doesnt read from my producer. I noticed that after calling the poll method thae the code does not execute the print "Hello" and there is no error message showing.

The code execute well but it's like if it breaks after the poll method

Note: my producer works well. I created a consumer to test it.

**Code**:

```
public class ConsumerApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create Propety dictionary for the producer Config settings
        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        KafkaConsumer<String, String> myconsumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(props);
        myconsumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("test"));

        try {
            while (true) {

                ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = myconsumer.poll(100);
                System.out.println("hello");
                // processing logic goes here
                for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
                    // processing records
                    System.out.println(String.format(record.topic(), record.partition(), record.offset(), record.key(),
                            record.value()));

                }

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // Closing Consumer
            myconsumer.close();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tested you Kafka env setup with KafkaConsoleProducer/Consumer?

Comment: Yes i did and it works but when i create my Consumer with java it doesnt work !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution i didnt set a connection with the zookeeper server , now that i did my consumer reads the Data ! Here is the code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    //Create Propety dictionary for the producer Config settings

    Properties props = new Properties();

    props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
    props.put("zookeeper.connect", "localhost:2181");
    props.put("group.id", "console");
    props.put("zookeeper.session.timeout.ms", "500");
    props.put("zookeeper.sync.timeout.ms", "500");
    props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");


    KafkaConsumer< String, String > myconsumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>  (props);
    myconsumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList("test"));

    try {
        while(true){


            ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = myconsumer.poll(100);

            // processing logic goes here
            for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
                    // processing records
                System.out.printf("offset = %d, key = %s, value = %s\n",
                        record.offset(), record.key(), record.value());

            }

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        // Closing Consumer
        myconsumer.close();
    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Long time ago I was playing with this example and it worked well, try it:

**Consumer:**

```
package com.spnotes.kafka.simple;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.errors.WakeupException;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Created by sunilpatil on 12/28/15.
 */
public class Consumer {
    private static Scanner in;

    public static void main(String[] argv)throws Exception{
        if (argv.length != 2) {
            System.err.printf("Usage: %s <topicName> <groupId>\n",
                    Consumer.class.getSimpleName());
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String topicName = argv[0];
        String groupId = argv[1];

        ConsumerThread consumerRunnable = new ConsumerThread(topicName,groupId);
        consumerRunnable.start();
        String line = "";
        while (!line.equals("exit")) {
            line = in.next();
        }
        consumerRunnable.getKafkaConsumer().wakeup();
        System.out.println("Stopping consumer .....");
        consumerRunnable.join();
    }

    private static class ConsumerThread extends Thread{
        private String topicName;
        private String groupId;
        private KafkaConsumer<String,String> kafkaConsumer;

        public ConsumerThread(String topicName, String groupId){
            this.topicName = topicName;
            this.groupId = groupId;
        }
        public void run() {
            Properties configProperties = new Properties();
            configProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
            configProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer");
            configProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
            configProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
            configProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "simple");

            //Figure out where to start processing messages from
            kafkaConsumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(configProperties);
            kafkaConsumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(topicName));
            //Start processing messages
            try {
                while (true) {
                    ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = kafkaConsumer.poll(100);
                    for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records)
                        System.out.println(record.value());
                }
            }catch(WakeupException ex){
                System.out.println("Exception caught " + ex.getMessage());
            }finally{
                kafkaConsumer.close();
                System.out.println("After closing KafkaConsumer");
            }
        }
        public KafkaConsumer<String,String> getKafkaConsumer(){
           return this.kafkaConsumer;
        }
    }
}
```

**Producer:**

```
package com.spnotes.kafka.simple;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;

import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Created by sunilpatil on 12/28/15.
 */
public class Producer {
    private static Scanner in;
    public static void main(String[] argv)throws Exception {
        if (argv.length != 1) {
            System.err.println("Please specify 1 parameters ");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        String topicName = argv[0];
        in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter message(type exit to quit)");

        //Configure the Producer
        Properties configProperties = new Properties();
        configProperties.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,"localhost:9092");
        configProperties.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,"org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer");
        configProperties.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,"org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

        org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Producer producer = new KafkaProducer(configProperties);
        String line = in.nextLine();
        while(!line.equals("exit")) {
            //TODO: Make sure to use the ProducerRecord constructor that does not take parition Id
            ProducerRecord<String, String> rec = new ProducerRecord<String, String>(topicName,line);
            producer.send(rec);
            line = in.nextLine();
        }
        in.close();
        producer.close();
    }
}
```

You can find another one nice example here: https://www.codenotfound.com/spring-kafka-consumer-producer-example.html